# Does my service panel require a dedicated ground?

Tags: electrical

I installed this 100 amp Homeline panel. I realized after I installed it that I hadn’t grounded the box. As seen in the picture I have two 120V hots and a neutral. I’m not sure if I can use the neutral as a ground or if I need to install a dedicated ground.

[image: 100 amp homeline box]

Comment: Your metal conduit _may_ provide a ground path. See the linked duplicates for more on that. If so, you may need to bond your neutral bus bars so that they're also grounded.

Comment: Yes, you need a dedicated ground path that is separated and isolated from the neutral wire.  The shell of non-flexible metal conduit will suffice. Grounds must be kept isolated from neutral. (the only exception is a pre-2008 subpanel which was wired with neutral-ground combined, or "Protective Earth And Neutral" as the British call it.  [Terrible idea, that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE).

Comment: According to [other posts](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/do-i-have-to-put-in-a-ground-wire-for-this-hundred-amp-box.749163), this is a subpanel.